# Changing nearfield monitors + D/A

Tags: nearfield, monitors, converter

Hi,

since I'm relocating to a new country, I'm thinking to sell my pair of Dynaudio BM15A and buy something smaller, more suitable for a studio apartment. Main use is for presets programming and design for sample libraries. I'm also looking for a good DA converter (or an audio interface with good DACs).

Any advice?

Thanks in advance,
Luca

Comment: There are too many options

Answer (score 2):

If you're are used to the Dynaudio BM15a, I'd try the BM6aII or a second hand mkI.

Regarding a converter/audio interface, I'd advice the RME Fireface UCX. I own and
use the UC and it's really nice. The UCX is a recent update and can also be used
on an iPad(2,3,4) (for a mobile setup, it could be handy).

But it largely depends on your budget..

Arnoud

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Prism Sound interfaces. I use the Orpheus unit myself and it sounds amazing. They now make a half sized Orpheus called the Lyra, that would be my pick for you if you're after the best D/A - http://www.prismsound.com/music_recording/products_subs/lyra/lyra_home.php

Answer (score 0):

the fireface ufx is cheaper but has the same specs, except less in and outputs and stuff. might be better for your budget... ;)

Answer (score 0):

i have a pair of Neumann KH120a and a RME babyface. just perfect (for me).